# How to enforce same origin policy in Express.js?

Tags: node.js, security, rest, express

Suppose I have the following URL route:

```
app.post('upvote', function(req, res) {
  // make a database a call to increase vote count
});
```

What can I do to prevent others from opening up a console and sending AJAX POST request on `www.mysite.com/upvote`? I'd like it so that only `www.mysite.com` is allowed to make that POST request and no one else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with bobince. `others` is a very general term.

If others belong to other sites (malicious sites on net).

- express has `csrf` middleware to protect from Cross Site Request
  Forgery. You can use it to prevent such a scenario. See the API docs
  [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#csrf).

If others are users of your own site

- then that is an authentication issue. Every request must be 
  checked before serving / executing it. You should implement a user
  authentication to prevent this situation. I use [passport](https://npmjs.org/package/passport), and
  ensure that user is authenticated before I actually run `app.post`
  handler.

Comment: Thanks, I should have been more clear about "others". It's the 2nd - users on my site. There is no authentication, it's available for public, and current as it stands all my REST API service is also publicly open. Should I rethink my application logic and control limit via IP Address?

Comment: Second issue, how can I enforce so that `POST` request is only executed if user clicks on an image, instead of opening a console and sending a `POST` request via a console?

Comment: IP restrictions will not help as IPs can change / users can be behind a proxy. If you want it to be open then let it be. Regarding the second issue, you can replicate the AJAX in your page via console. But using session / prior AJAX calls and server validation, you can make it difficult if not impossible.

Comment: Thanks. Seomeone has suggested using nonce (number used once) to make it difficult for potential attackers. But I've had some problems using Express sessions with Backbone on the client side, but that's a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246500/express-3-the-req-session-is-undefined

Answer (score 4):

> What can I do to prevent others from opening up a console and sending AJAX POST request

Who is "others"?

If others==users of the site... there is nothing you can do to stop them sending whatever requests they like, using the JavaScript console or any other means. You can't trust the client, so you have to have server-side authorisation: requiring that the user be logged into an account, and registering that the account has upvoted so can't vote again.

If others==admins of other sites (by serving script to their users that causes submissions to your site)... it isn't possible for JavaScript on another site to cause an AJAX POST request, or at least not unless you deliberately opt into that using [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). But it's quite possible for them to cause a POST by simply creating a `<form>` pointing to your address and submitting it.

This is a classic [Cross Site Request Forgery](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/09/cross-site-request-forgeries-and-you.html) problem. The widely-accepted solution to XSRF issues is to include a secret token as a parameter in each POST (form or AJAX) submission. That secret token is associated with the logged-in state of the user, either by being stored in the server-side session, or replicated in a client-side cookie. Either way an attacker from another site isn't capable of getting hold of a token that is valid for the logged-in user, so they can't fake the request.

You need XSRF protection on *all* actions that have a direct effect, whether AJAX or form-based POSTs.