# Backbone.js + Express 3: The req.session is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I am pulling my hair out here, I've done Express session in the past, I've followed every Stackoverflow post on related issue. No luck.

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico')); 
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'ponies' }));
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/api/characters', function(req, res) {        
    // Initially false/undefined
    if (req.session.hasViewed) {
      return res.send(allCharacters.slice(req.session.currentCounter, req.session.currentCounter+2));
    }

    req.session.hasViewed = true;
    req.session.currentCounter = counter;

    res.send(allCharacters.slice(counter, counter + 2));
    counter = counter + 2;
});
```

Why do `req.sessionhasViewed` and `req.session.currentCounter` are always undefined? Actually, not always, sometimes on the 6th or 7th tries the session object kicks in and it works. Which is even worse than never working.

**Background:** The view should display 2 characters initially. If the user presses F5 to refresh the browser, the same two characters should be displayed again, until he/she clicks on one of them. Clearing the session object is performed in another function.

**Update**: I was pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> repeatedly; when you see *Personal* log message that's when the session kicks-in.

[image]

**Update 2:** Ok, so I don't know if this makes any difference, but the code above is located in `/api/characters`. But the actual URL when that API is loaded at "/" route via a Backbone Router that instantiates a new view for that route.

Comment: Where does `counter` come from? Is it a global variable? Is it meant to be shared by all requests?

Comment: @robertklep yes counter is a global variable that gets incremented on every unique request.